How can I properly reprint a readline prompt on SIGINT?
I have the following signal handler established:
void    sig_handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGINT)
    {
        printf("\n");
        rl_on_new_line();
        rl_replace_line("", 0);
        rl_redisplay();
    }
}

This works fine when at the readline prompt but if I run a blocking command (say cat) The prompt gets printed twice on the same line.
If I remove rl_redisplay(); it works when running cat but the prompt never gets printed when readline() is waiting for input. I have read this question, and SA_RESTART is set in sa.sa_flags.

What does the GNU rl_* functions contain? Are there only posix signal-safe calls in those? Please provide a [mre].

You can not do that safely from within a signal handler.  And any code examples you see that do so are just plain wrong.  Such examples can appear to work in simple, contrived code that doesn't involve anything complex, but they are still wrong.
Per 7.1.4 Use of library functions, paragraph 4 of the (draft) C11 standard:

The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration.

As noted by footnote 188:

Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions.

Thus, it's not safe to call any C standard function such as printf() from within a signal handler.
But POSIX allows for some calls to be made from within a signal handler:

...
... the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object other than errno with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or if the signal handler calls any function defined in this standard other than one of the functions listed in the following table.
The following table defines a set of functions that shall be async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can call them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions.

If the function called is not on that table, you can not safely call it from within a signal handler.
Linux specifics can be found in the Linux signal-safety man page:

An async-signal-safe function is one that can be safely called
from within a signal handler.  Many functions are not async-signal-safe.  In particular, nonreentrant functions are generally
unsafe to call from a signal handler.
The kinds of issues that render a function unsafe can be quickly
understood when one considers the implementation of the stdio
library, all of whose functions are not async-signal-safe.

What you can do is set a flag to reprint the prompt when the process exits:
volatile sig_atomic_t reprintPrompt = 0;

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGINT)
    {
        reprintPrompt = 1;
    }
}

...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...

    if (reprintPrompt)
    {
        printf("\n");
        rl_on_new_line();
        rl_replace_line("", 0);
        rl_redisplay();
    }
    return(0);
}


That's not possible, since readline() blocks.

@user39350 Then you need to come up with some other approach that works in your context.  To get a better answer, you'll have to supply a lot more information about how you're using readline().

If you are creating a process to execute cat, it could be that when the process receives a signal, the handler from the parent is called, then you could try ignoring SIGINT at the parent process, since the execution of the child process would be terminated by default, then after forking and after waiting for the pid you reinstall the signal handler.
Hope it works.

And of course when you catch the exit stat from "waitpid", you'ld have to print a newline
